# View App Preview Video from App Store with web browser

Tags: ios, itunes, ios-appstore, video, web-browser

There is a [web preview](https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8) out there, but that is different from the App Store app directly on an iPhone. E.g. I can't watch the video, which some app developer offer to show/explain an app. See [App Preview Video](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/) for more details, what video I mean.

It is also not in the XML from the [iTunes Search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604886/how-to-get-info-from-the-apple-itunes-app-store-and-mac-app-store).

Is there an option to access this video from any web browser instead of using the App Store app on an iOS device?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking?  As it's currently written, I can't tell what the problem is or what you already did to resolve it yourself.

Comment: @fsb:I'm talking about [App Preview Videos](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/). What I did? I got managed to find out the iTunes web preview link and I got the XML from the iTunes Search API.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but that explanation didn't help.  What I understand so far is that there's an app in the App Store that has a app preview video.  You can't watch the video (for some reason) by clicking on it in the App Store.  You want to know how to watch the video.  Is that correct?

Comment: @fsb: I can watch the video with the App Store app, but I want to watch it with my web browser too (without using the device).

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to watch these videos on a browser.  None of Apple's docs indicate these can be viewed anywhere other than a device.

Comment: You may be right, but that is somewhat inconsistent from Apple if they provide a web preview, but not include all details ..

Comment: The videos are formatted by device and they don't offer a web version size to developers.  I don't see it as inconsistent because you can open iTunes on your computer and see the videos there.

Comment: How do you open it in iTunes? In the latest versions of iTunes the apps have been removed or not?

Comment: @testing have you found a solution?

Comment: @fsb can you please share more info?

Comment: @noitseuq share more info about what?  It looks like the last comments are where this is right now and no more info is available.  If you have a new question, see [ask].